# Django ModelForm custom validation: How to access submitted field values

Tags: django, validation, modelform

I have the below model form and want to add custom validation to a field called 'billable_work'.

How do I access a field 'project' which was submitted in the form?  I want to check the value of project ('p' in the below example) but can't locate the proper syntax so that I can test the submitted value.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entries
        exclude = ('billable_work','notes')  

    billable_work = forms.BooleanField()
    notes = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,required=False)

    def clean_billable_work(self):
        b = self.cleaned_data['billable_work']
        p = form.fields['project']

        if b == True and p == 523:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Entries cannot be both billable and NONE: Indirect."))
        return self.cleaned_data['billable_work']
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you want to override the [clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method on your model rather than the clean method of a specific form field. From the docs -

> This method should be used to provide custom model validation, and to
>   modify attributes on your model if desired. For instance, you could
>   use it to automatically provide a value for a field, or to do
>   validation that requires access to more than a single field.

If you did want to put the validation in the form then the `clean()` method on the form provides similar functionality (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)).

Comment: Thanks for the link in the docs.  I was looking for the syntax self.cleaned_data.get('project').  In order to test the value I have to convert this to a string.  Is this a proper/valid method?

Comment: Interesting note-- I'm working to add custom validation to an admin form. Docs for Django 3.1 point out the clean() method does not run for admin interface, and you must use [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin).